# How do I tell IntelliJ about groovy installed with brew on OSX

Tags: java, macos, intellij-idea, groovy

I'm running:

- IntelliJ Ultimate 2016.3
- Homebrew 1.1.2
- OS X 10.11.5 El Capitan

I ran `brew install groovy` which resulted in groovy being installed in `/usr/local/Cellar/groovy/2.4.7/`. Brew also added a symlink: `/usr/local/bin/groovy -> ../Cellar/groovy/2.4.7/bin/groovy`

When I open the groovy project in IntelliJ, it gives me an option to Configure a Groovy SDK. I haven't set this up yet, so I get a "Create" button, which launches finder. From what I can tell there's nothing that I can select to make IntelliJ happy. I've tried `/user/local/bin/groovy`, `/user/local/Cellar/groovy`, `/user/local/Cellar/groovy/2.4.7`, `/user/local/Cellar/groovy/2.4.7/bin` etc. No mater which I choose, IntelliJ doesn't accept the library and continues to tell me "Error: library is not specified".

Does anyone know how I'm supposed to go about telling IntelliJ where groovy is?

Answer (score 144):

1. Install groovysdk:

   ```
   brew remove groovy
   brew install groovysdk
   ```
2. Set `GROOVY_HOME`, otherwise IntelliJ reports as broken installation:

   ```
   export GROOVY_HOME=/usr/local/opt/groovy/libexec
   ```
3. Point IntelliJ to the installed directory, e.g.:

   ```
   /usr/local/Cellar/groovysdk/2.4.7/libexec
   ```

Comment: Use <CMD><shift> <.> to see hidden directory tree in the Finder

Comment: That was so painful to figure out - thanks for posting this tip

Comment: you also do cmd + g to navigate to a specific folder

Comment: IntelliJ 2018.1 doesn't report the installation as broken for me, even though GROOVY_HOME isn't set. Perhaps this has been fixed already.

Comment: I managed to browse to this hidden folder (I had to press and hold these keys to make it work). Now Idea doesn't create any SDK, after I "open" that directory. What's wrong now?...

Comment: @kindjacket its CMD SHIFT g  (good tip though, wouldn't have tried it without having tried your advice first)

Comment: GROOVY_HOME path should have groovysdk and not groovy, isn't it?

Comment: why to remove groovy to install groovy sdk?

Answer (score 48):

```
brew install groovysdk
```

- Right-Click on Project Root Folder or if a Config Wizard Pops up at the top of your windows we can click that link.
- Select **"Add Framework Support"**.
  NOTE: if you don't see it, just press <kbd>⌘ command</kbd><kbd>⇧ shift</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> and type "Add Framework Support" (i.e. use the ["Find Action"](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/guide/tutorials/presenting/find-action/) command).
- Scroll down and select **Groovy**.

  If it does not show in the list, it's because it already has the framework added.
- If Groovy has not been added to IntellJ then select **Create...**
- navigate to `/usr/local/Cellar/groovysdk/<version>/libexec/`.
  E.g: `/usr/local/Cellar/groovysdk/2.4.11/libexec/`

**Gotcha:** if it shows the file browser, bit does not let you view your `/usr/local` file path, you need to press <kbd>⇧ shift</kbd><kbd>⌘ command</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> to open a dialog where you can type the path of any folder that you want to open.

Done.

Comment: I just tried with IntelliJ 2019.2.3 and `shift + command + g` wasn't needed.

Comment: This actually works with the 2019 versions of IntelliJ.  Nothing else posted here worked (or was specific enough).

Answer (score 15):

`/usr/local/opt/groovy/libexec`.

use `brew info groovy` to print help:

```
==> Caveats
  You should set GROOVY_HOME:
    export GROOVY_HOME=/usr/local/opt/groovy/libexec
```

Comment: This was useful to know, but ultimately didn't fix things. I think there might be a problem on the intelliJ side. It wound up wanting a folder named groovy-x.y.z, which I got manually from the Groovy website and unzipped under ~/tools/groovy-x.y.z/

Answer (score 14):

I did this with Intellij IDEA 2016.3 on OS X.

I am able to configure this under **Project Settings** -> **Global Libraries**.

1. Add a new global library  by clicking the `+` and select `Java`
2. Navigate to the location `homebrew` installed Groovy, `/usr/local/Cellar/groovy/2.4.7` and select all the JAR files in the `libexec/lib` directory.
3. Set the name to `groovy-2.4.7`, or whatever works for you.

Comment: Only thing that worked for me. IntelliJ does not make this easy.

Answer (score 5):

**It is very easy to do:**

**Install groovy**:

```
brew install groovy
```

**Point IntelliJ to the following directory:**

```
/usr/local/Cellar/groovysdk/<version>/libexec
```

You will see that intellij will get all the required dependencies

Comment: there is no folder as groovysdk in Cellar?

Answer (score 2):

Because I could not select /usr in the open dialog, I used to 'go to folder' function of finder and created a favorite entry for /usr/local/opt/groovy/libexec
which worked.

Comment: cmd + shift + . will show "hidden" folders such as /usr

Comment: you can also open it via `open /path/to/folder` in terminal and then drag that folder to the favorites bar.